# Get all css root variables in array using javascript and change the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, css-variables

I am using css root variables in my project for dynamically changing the colors of all elements anytime.

My css looks like

```
:root{
  --primaryColor:aliceblue;
  --secondaryColor:blue;
  --errorColor:#cc2511;
}
```

used in css

```
.contentCss {
  background-color: var(--primaryColor);
}
```

I can access variable in javascript as follows to change value dynamically

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primaryColor', 'green');
```

It works fine. I want to get all variables inside an array and according to that change the values of each variable dynamically.

Answer (score 37):

this script will return an array of root variables in all stylesheets, served from the domain. Out of domain stylesheets are not accessible due to CORS policies.

```
Array.from(document.styleSheets)
  .filter(
    sheet =>
      sheet.href === null || sheet.href.startsWith(window.location.origin)
  )
  .reduce(
    (acc, sheet) =>
      (acc = [
        ...acc,
        ...Array.from(sheet.cssRules).reduce(
          (def, rule) =>
            (def =
              rule.selectorText === ":root"
                ? [
                    ...def,
                    ...Array.from(rule.style).filter(name =>
                      name.startsWith("--")
                    )
                  ]
                : def),
          []
        )
      ]),
    []
  );
```

Note: a `root:` rule in a lower order stylesheet will override a parent `root` rule.

Answer (score 7):

I needed a similar solution today. Here's a [quick one on codepen](https://codepen.io/taysim/pen/qgrbyz?editors=0111).

```
// could pass in an array of specific stylesheets for optimization
function getAllCSSVariableNames(styleSheets = document.styleSheets){
   var cssVars = [];
   // loop each stylesheet
   for(var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++){
      // loop stylesheet's cssRules
      try{ // try/catch used because 'hasOwnProperty' doesn't work
         for( var j = 0; j < styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++){
            try{
               // loop stylesheet's cssRules' style (property names)
               for(var k = 0; k < styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].style.length; k++){
                  let name = styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].style[k];
                  // test name for css variable signiture and uniqueness
                  if(name.startsWith('--') && cssVars.indexOf(name) == -1){
                     cssVars.push(name);
                  }
               }
            } catch (error) {}
         }
      } catch (error) {}
   }
   return cssVars;
}

function getElementCSSVariables (allCSSVars, element = document.body, pseudo){
   var elStyles = window.getComputedStyle(element, pseudo);
   var cssVars = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < allCSSVars.length; i++){
      let key = allCSSVars[i];
      let value = elStyles.getPropertyValue(key)
      if(value){cssVars[key] = value;}
   }
   return cssVars;
}

var cssVars = getAllCSSVariableNames();
console.log(':root variables', getElementCSSVariables(cssVars, document.documentElement));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can declare an associative array with the keys as the node property with their values, then use a function to set your theme:

```
var primaryColor = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--primaryColor');
var secondaryColor = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--secondaryColor');
var errorColor = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--errorColor');

var themeColors = {}
themeColors["--primaryColor"] = primaryColor;
themeColors["--secondaryColor"] = secondaryColor;
themeColors["--errorColor"] = errorColor;

function setTheme(theme) {
     for (key in theme) {
        let color = theme[key];
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(key, color);
   }
 }
```

A working example I used with Atom and Bootstrap:

```
        var backgroundColor = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--blue');
        backgroundColor = "#dc3545";

        function setTheme(theme) {
          for (key in theme) {
            let color = theme[key];
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty(key, color);
          }
        }

        var theme = {}
        theme["--blue"] = backgroundColor;

        setTheme(theme);
```

[image: Override default colors]

**>>Edit<<**

Nadeem clarified the question a bit better with a comment below, unfortunately however I've learned that `:root` can be accessed with get `Window.getComputedStyle()` however this doesn't return CSS Variable declarations.

A hack around this is just to read the css file, parse it for variables and stuff them into an associative array, but even this assumes you know where to get that css file...

```
        //an associative array that will hold our values
        var cssVars = {};

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', './css/style.css', true);

        request.onload = function() {
          if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
              //Get all CSS Variables in the document
              var matches = request.responseText.match(/(--)\w.+;/gi);

              //Get all CSS Variables in the document
              for(let match in matches) {
                  var property = matches[match];
                  //split the Variable name from its value
                  let splitprop = property.split(":")

                  //turn the value into a string
                  let value = splitprop[1].toString()

                  cssVars[splitprop[0]] = value.slice(0, -1); //remove ;
              }

              // console.log(cssVars);
              // > Object {--primaryColor: "aliceblue", --secondaryColor: "blue", --errorColor: "#cc2511"}

              // console.log(Object.keys(cssVars));
              // > ["--primaryColor", "--secondaryColor", "--errorColor" ]

              setTheme(cssVars)

            } else {
              // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
            }
          };

          request.onerror = function() {
            console.log("There was a connection error");
          };

          request.send();



          function setTheme(theme) {
            var keys = Object.keys(theme)

            for (key in keys) {
              let prop = keys[key]
              let color = theme[keys[key]];

              console.log(prop, color);
              // --primaryColor aliceblue etc...
            }
          }
```

Comment: suppose i have 200 variables in css so i have to write this line var primaryColor = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--primaryColor'); 200 times. I want it dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

If you know all your variable will be placed inside the `:root` and it's the first declaration in your first CSS file, you can try something like this and you will get all the variable inside an Object:

```js
var declaration = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0];
var allVar = declaration.style.cssText.split(";");

var result = {}
for (var i = 0; i < allVar.length; i++) {
  var a = allVar[i].split(':');
  if (a[0] !== "")
    result[a[0].trim()] = a[1].trim();
}

console.log(result);
var keys = Object.keys(result);
console.log(keys);

//we change the first variable
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(keys[0], 'green');

//we change the variable  --secondary-color
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(keys[keys.indexOf("--secondary-color")], 'red');
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: aliceblue;
  --secondary-color: blue;
  --error-color: #cc2511
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  border:1px solid var(--secondary-color)
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
```

Comment: interesting solution, quite clean, I considered using `.cssRules[0]` but I found that only the first `:root` element was read. if you have multiple ones from different sources, say local and CDN, only the first will be read.

Comment: @RLoniello yes as you may notice i used `0` index and if you follow them you will see that i took the first CSS file and the first rule inside this CSS file ... so you can do the same with the other, the only thing you have to know is the order and indexes ... this is the small drawback :) but if you know your CSS files it won't be an issue ;)

Comment: @RLoniello use console.log with `document.styleSheets` to see what inside it and you will understand ;)

Comment: yeah I get it :) Just watch out for the loading order of your CDN stylesheets. :P

Comment: @RLoniello yes if you get the orders it easy ... but if not you can make the code more complicated where you loop through all the styles to get the variable .. so almost the same thing i have done but with all the style .. you simply need to add an `if else` to check that the style is a varialbe (it should start with `--`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another in typescript, where I continued work that RLoniello mentioned. It also outputs it as a JS object, that is converts --font-family: "Verdana" to fontFamily: "Verdana".

```js
const CssKeyToJsKey = (key: string) =>
    key.replace('--', '').replace(/-./g, (x) => x.toUpperCase()[1]);

const getAllCSSVariableNames = (styleSheets: StyleSheetList = document.styleSheets) => {
    const cssVars = [];

    Array.from(styleSheets).forEach((styleSheet) => {
        Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).forEach((rule) => {
            if (!rule || !rule['style']) {
                return;
            }

            Array.from(rule['style']).forEach((style: string) => {
                if (style.startsWith('--') && cssVars.indexOf(style) == -1) {
                    cssVars.push(style);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    return cssVars;
};

const getElementCSSVariables = (
    allCSSVars: Array<string>,
    element: HTMLElement = document.body,
    pseudo: string | undefined = ''
) => {
    const elStyles = window.getComputedStyle(element, pseudo);
    const cssVars = {};

    allCSSVars.forEach((key) => {
        const value = elStyles.getPropertyValue(key);

        if (value) {
            cssVars[CssKeyToJsKey(key)] = value;
        }
    });

    return cssVars;
};

export const getAllCSSVariables = (): Record<string, string> => {
    const cssVars = getAllCSSVariableNames();

    return getElementCSSVariables(cssVars, document.documentElement);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Map to a named Object without using `.getComputedStyle()`

```js
/* Retrieve all --root CSS variables
*  rules into a named Object
*  Without using getComputedStyle (read string only)
*/
console.log(

  [...document.styleSheets[0].rules]
   .map(a => a.cssText.split(" ")[0] === ":root" ?
     a.cssText.split("{")[1].split("}")[0].split(";") : null)
   .filter(a => a !== null)[0]
   .map((a) => a.split(": "))
   .filter(a => a[0] !== " ")
   .reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v[0].slice(1)] : v[1] }), {})

)
```

```css
:root {
    --gold: hsl(48,100%,50%);
    --gold-lighter: hsl(48,22%,30%);
    --gold-darker: hsl(45,100%,47%);
    --silver: hsl(210,6%,72%);
    --silver-lighter: hsl(0,0%,26%);
    --silver-darker: hsl(210,3%,61%);
    --bronze: hsl(28,38%,67%);
    --bronze-lighter: hsl(28,13%,27%);
    --bronze-darker: hsl(28,31%,52%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional approach to get all `:root` CSS variables that won't throw type errors if you're using a stricter TypeScript configuration:

```js
const rootCssVariables: string[] = Array.from(document.styleSheets)
  .flatMap((styleSheet: CSSStyleSheet) => Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules))
  .filter(
    (cssRule: CSSRule): cssRule is CSSStyleRule =>
      cssRule instanceof CSSStyleRule && cssRule.selectorText === ':root',
  )
  .flatMap((cssRule: CSSStyleRule) => Array.from(cssRule.style))
  .filter((style: string) => style.startsWith('--'))

console.log(rootCssVariables)
// e.g. ['--background-color', '--text-color', etc...]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get var color name only then try

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style
```