# Reset style properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm setting properties of the :root pseudo class in this manner:

```
$(":root")[0].style.setProperty(variable, value);
```

If I wanted to reset all the properties precedently set, how can I do? Without specifying every variable set, assigning empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way, just reset the style object:

```
$(':root')[0].style = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Umm.. how about you use [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)`:`[`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset). So:

```
$(":root")[0].style.setProperty("all", "unset");
```

Demo:

```css
h1 {
   color: red;
   all: unset;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello this should not be red nor should have default h1 styles</h1>
```

Comment: @Keaire Yeah, doesn't work for variables. There isn't even an API to get all variables on an element. So you'll have to go through all declarations in the StyleSheet like answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760274/get-all-css-root-variables-in-array-using-javascript-and-change-the-values)

Comment: Found a way: `$(':root')[0].style = {}`
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Keaire You're welcome! Won't work if the variables are declared in a stylesheet, but looks like that isn't your case. Also this is very neat hahaha xDDD