# How to read css variable in angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, google-chrome

Why I can't get the css variable content in angular?

I add variable in style.css as following:

```
:root {
  --foo: "string";
}
```

and try to get the value by `getPropertyValue` in app.component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const y = document.body.parentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--foo');
    console.log({ y }); // logs: "".
  }
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-bush-vg00u?file=/src/styles.css:123-153)

I using Chrome last version.

Comment: Have you tried this 
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--foo') ?

Comment: thanks. with `getComputedStyle` it's works. but it's trigger paint event and it's impact performance

Comment: If you know where it is set use that element to get the property otherwise I think you have to use @RomanA suggestion if the element you are looking at is not the one that set the property.

Comment: As the others have suggested, the `style` property only contains the CSS that is defined via the [`style` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style#getting_style_information).

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760274/get-all-css-root-variables-in-array-using-javascript-and-change-the-values) for another solution. basically manipulating `document.styleSheets[x].cssRules[y]`