# How to get the names of all involved computed CSS custom properties of a given HTML element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

In JavaScript/DOM there's `getComputedStyle` to get access to all the computed style properties of a given element and then there's `getComputedStyle(...).getPropertyValue(...)` the get the actual value of a computed style property.

But how do I get the names of all involved custom properties (those that start with '--')? TYVMIA

Comment: Based on [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760274/get-all-css-root-variables-in-array-using-javascript-and-change-the-values), it seems there's no easy way. Instead, you'd have to dig through the stylesheets themselves.

Comment: You can get all the CSS variables that are available for that element through getComputedStyle, but it depends on what is meant by ‘involved’. They may or may not be being actually used in the styling.

Comment: @AHaworth With "all involved variables" I mean "all custom properties that are set in the context of the given element". Please find here a non-working demo: codepen.io/natasha42/pen/podNzaE (ouput should be: --some-prop)

Comment: Filter produces an array not a string.

Comment: @AHaworth, of course your are right, my bad. I meant "... (output should be: `['--some-prop']`)". I want an array of all the names of the (in the context/subtree) involved custom properties.